# How to update text on trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I have created a game, in which an helicopter goes through a ring. So what I wanted to do is that when this helicopter passes through the ring I want the text on GUI to update incrementally 10 times (which is basically a score card).

Could anyone help me with the script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put game object with trigger collider inside the ring. The add script to this game object with [OnTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html)  method. It will be called when your helicopter will pass through the ring. So you can add score update in same method.